# Get Visual Studio Solution Files and Folders

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to develop a `CustomControl` and I need to enumerate Files and Folder inside `Solution`. Is there anyway to do this?

**--Edit:** 
The scenario is:
Actually I'm trying to create a simple binding control that enumerate only classes which is inherited from a specified class then user can select class and bind it to related Form's controls, to do this I couldn't find anything useful in design-mode, that's what I ask to enumerate solution files and folders.

Comment: it is a file system, i think you can do this..i ll' try this for sure

Comment: Yes I know, but I want only files included in solution.

Comment: deep dive into file properties...hmm

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do that requires knowing the file structure of the Solution project (edit the original question with this info)? It seems like a very odd request and if you help explain the bigger picture of what you are trying to do people will be able to give you better answers. See [the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for more info. You gave us `Y`, tell us `X` and we may be able to give you a better solution.

Comment: you can use the `EnvDTE` API, More info can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte(v=vs.80).aspx
or examples here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36219/Exploring-EnvDTE

Comment: I agree with @sa_ddam213 if you are creating a control that behaves a special way while in the designer (its not [hard to do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx)) you should use the EnvDTE classes to talk to visual studio and query information about the project. If you are not running inside visual studio, the compiled exe does not know about the solution it was built in, it can't tell you. That's why I asked for more info, if you explain what your control is doing that it requires knowing what is in the solution we can tell you what to use.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I updated my post, take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is via the `EnvDTE` class in the Visual Studio Extension API. There's a good example built-in: open the Macro Explorer and navigate to Utilities/ListProj. Then right-click and choose 'Edit' to show the code that implements it in Visual Basic.  This should give you enough information to be able to replicate the logic in C# (the class and method names are the same)

[image: Macro explorer]

The idea of it is simple - you just enumerate the `ProjectItems()` members recursively. Each node may itself have further `ProjectItems()` members

```
Dim project As Project
project = DTE.ActiveSolutionProjects(0)
ListProjAux(project.ProjectItems(), 0)

Sub ListProjAux(ByVal projectItems As EnvDTE.ProjectItems, ByVal level As Integer)
  Dim projectItem As EnvDTE.ProjectItem
  For Each projectItem In projectItems
    projectItems2 = projectItem.ProjectItems
       ListProjAux(projectItems2, level + 1)
  Next
End Sub
```

Note that I've omitted some of the null checks in this example, but they're in the ListProj sample.

Answer (score 0):

This is gonna be very simple.

Yes you can get the path of the project's solution file and can process the file inside it.

```
string solutionPath = Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.FullName;
```

Comment: this will return whole files and surely excluded files and folders.

Comment: Excluded files and folders will be shown only in Visual Studio. There is nothing like excluded or included files concept in the folder structure. So when you go to this location, all the excluded and included files will be available. So you can retrieve all files and folders.

Comment: This will return the solution folder path. And from that you have to retrieve the wanted files.

Comment: I know that, I meant to I don't want to get excluded files if I use basic file and folder system. I need something to give me only included and available files and folders in vs-structure.