# Visual Studio Extension: How to get the "path" of a solution folder on selection?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, vsix

Previous question:
[Visual Studio Extension: How to disable native command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566625/visual-studio-extension-how-to-disable-native-command)

I build an extension that manages correctly Git Modules and, to do so, I have a folder in the solution called SubModules.

I managed to add my context menu to the solution file and to the project files, but I would like to disable some native commands when right-clicking on my SubModules folder (i.e. Remove, Add).

I now know how to disable the native commands I want, but to do so, I need to get the "path" of the selected Solution Folder.

I tried to implement IVsSelectionEvents, but no luck (o is not null before casting):

```
public int OnSelectionChanged(IVsHierarchy pHierOld, uint itemidOld, IVsMultiItemSelect pMISOld, ISelectionContainer pSCOld, IVsHierarchy pHierNew, uint itemidNew, IVsMultiItemSelect pMISNew, ISelectionContainer pSCNew)
{
    var o = GetProjectItem(pHierNew, itemidNew);
    return VSConstants.S_OK;
}

private static ProjectItem GetProjectItem(IVsHierarchy hierarchy, uint itemId)
{
    object o;
    if (hierarchy.GetProperty(itemId, (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_ExtObject, out o) == VSConstants.S_OK)
    {
        var t = o as SolutionFolder; // ==> null

        return o as ProjectItem; // ==> null
    }
    return null;
}
```

Using the code I had (from the other question) (where I want to find the "path", but I could have managed with the above "solution"), I tried to cast to SolutionFolder or to FileProperties... still no luck; even though MSDN tells the returned objects are supposed to be of type FileProperties. Exploring with QuickWatch on `(Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(selectionContainerPtr) as ISelectionContainer)`, I can go in the see the private property `_nodes` and there, I can see my SolutionFolder node and go up using its Parent property to ensure it is a folder I want to block commands. Here is the actual code:

```
private static void CommandEvents_BeforeExecute(string Guid, int ID, object CustomIn, object CustomOut, ref bool CancelDefault)
{
    string name = GetCommandName(Guid, ID);

    if (name == "Project.AddNewSolutionFolder")
    {
        CancelDefault = true;
    }
    if (name == "Edit.Delete")
    {
        CancelDefault = true;

        IVsMultiItemSelect multiItemSelect = null;
        IntPtr hierarchyPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr selectionContainerPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        uint itemid = 0;

        int hr = monitorSelection.GetCurrentSelection(out hierarchyPtr, out itemid, out multiItemSelect, out selectionContainerPtr);
        object[] selected = new object[2];
        (Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(selectionContainerPtr) as ISelectionContainer).GetObjects(2, 1, selected);


        var t = selected[0] as VSLangProj.FileProperties; // ==> null
        var t2 = selected[0] as SolutionFolder; // ==> null
        var b = 1;
    }

    if (name == "View.Branch")
    {
        //TODO: Could disable this command if not able to find the branch changing command (that would be cancelled and launch ours)
        menuBranchOpened = true;
    }

    if (menuBranchOpened)
    {
        var a = 1;
    }

}
```

I was inspired by and tried (none worked except the above one seems to be really near) :

- [Get Visual Studio Solution Files and Folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462946/get-visual-studio-solution-files-and-folders)
- [Visual Studio Extension: Get the path of the current selected file in the Solution Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677290/visual-studio-extension-get-the-path-of-the-current-selected-file-in-the-soluti)
- [How to get the details of the selected item in solution explorer using vs package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194880/how-to-get-the-details-of-the-selected-item-in-solution-explorer-using-vs-packag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, exploring (more) the website of the other person who answered me for my previous question, I finally found it. So I will share a method I made to know what type of items are selected in the Solution Explorer.

```
applicationObject = await ServiceProvider.GetGlobalServiceAsync(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE2; // Was initiate in a method

private enum SelectionTypes
{
    Other = 0,
    InSubModules = 1,
    IsAFolder = 2,
    IsAProject = 4,
    InAProject = 8
}

private static List<SelectionTypes> GetSelectionTypes()
{
    ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
    var selectionTypes = new List<SelectionTypes>();

    EnvDTE.UIHierarchy solutionExplorer = applicationObject.ToolWindows.SolutionExplorer;
    object[] items = solutionExplorer.SelectedItems as object[];
    //{ Name = "WindowBase" FullName = "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.DTE.WindowBase"}
    if (items.Length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            var selectionType = SelectionTypes.Other;
            var selectedItem = items[0] as EnvDTE.UIHierarchyItem;
            var currentItem = selectedItem;
            var subModulesParentsCount = 0;
            var countingSubModulesParents = false;
            var nbParents = -1;

            if (currentItem.Object.GetType().FullName == "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAProject") selectionType |= SelectionTypes.IsAProject;
            if (currentItem.Object.GetType().FullName == "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAFolderItem") selectionType |= SelectionTypes.IsAFolder;

            while (currentItem != null)
            {
                nbParents++;
                if (countingSubModulesParents) subModulesParentsCount++;

                if (currentItem.Name == "SubModules")
                {
                    subModulesParentsCount = 0;
                    countingSubModulesParents = true;
                }

                if (currentItem.Object.GetType().FullName == "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAProject") selectionType |= SelectionTypes.InAProject;

                currentItem = currentItem.Collection.Parent as EnvDTE.UIHierarchyItem;
            }

            if (selectionType == SelectionTypes.Other && nbParents != 0) selectionType |= SelectionTypes.IsAFolder;

            if (subModulesParentsCount == 1)
            {
                selectionType |= SelectionTypes.InSubModules;
            }

            selectionTypes.Add(selectionType);
        }
    }

    return selectionTypes;
}
```

Comment: I've been trying for a very long time to figure out where to get `ToolWindows` within Package Manager Console.  Your `applicationObject` should be the same thing as `$dte` there.  `$dte` has a `Windows` collection of type `WindowBase` (not at all the same thing).  None of it's other properties have anything like `ToolWindows`.  Any idea why I can't find it?

Comment: @dudeNumber4 Unfortunately I don’t and I am not working there anymore and I don’t have access right now to a similar setup. I hope you will find a way!